# How do you stop MySQL on a Mac OS install?

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed MySQL via [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts). What is the command I need to stop the server (I need to test how my application behave when MySQL is dead)?

Answer (score 534, accepted):

There are different cases depending on whether you installed [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) with the official binary installer, using [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), or using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

### Homebrew

```
brew services start mysql
brew services stop mysql
brew services restart mysql
```

### MacPorts

```
sudo port load mysql57-server
sudo port unload mysql57-server
```

Note: this is persistent after a reboot.

### Binary installer

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart
```

Comment: Thanks a ton - I had the stop and start commands, but didn't know about/think about trying restart.  After using the stop command, start would do nothing, as would starting from the MySQL System Preferences panel.

Comment: In my case it was slightly different, because the mysql version number was added in the plist file. It was like that:

    sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
    sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist

Comment: And for me, /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/org.macports.mysql5.plist

Comment: And for homebrew: `launchctl (un)load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

Comment: @vrinek Tahnk you - That did it for me - Except the file is `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist`

Comment: Why not just `sudo mysql.server stop` etc.? Any proper installation, regardless of method, should have put that in your PATH. I've installed through Homebrew and mentioned short form works fine.

Comment: If you have [Homebrew Services](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services) installed, you can use `brew services stop mysql` and `brew services start mysql`. (Also `restart`, and `run` which starts for the current session only.)

Comment: @MarkusAmaltheaMagnuson I get `.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/TRSS-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).` but not with the `launchctl` or `brew services` approach.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Kept getting this error: /Users/charlie/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist: No such file or directory

Comment: This worked for me ```sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist```

Answer (score 147):

For those who used homebrew to install MySQL use the following commands below to start, stop, or restart MySQL

**Brew start**

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server start
```

**Brew restart**

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server restart
```

**Brew stop**

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop
```

Comment: For me, the install directory by homebrew is `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.23/bin/`

Answer (score 80):

You can always use command "mysqladmin shutdown"

Comment: The commands above didn't work for me. This one did.  Not sure what the difference is in my setup, but thanks.

Comment: Even though it may work, if you're using MacPorts and run this, launchctl will not realize mysql has stopped and will complain if you try to start it (load).  Using launchctl is thus preferable.

Comment: Also although this works for shutting down the server, it won't do anything to help you bring it back up when you want to restart it.

Comment: Remember to add -p and enter your mysql root password when prompted. At my setup where mysql is installed with MacPorts mysql restarted, and reloaded the config, which was the target for my action.

Comment: `sudo /opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysqladmin shutdown` if your mysql comes from MacPorts

Comment: Works fine for homebrew installed mysql. I had to execute the command as sudo (i.e. `sudo mysqladmin shutdown`)

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. I just needed to add `sudo` to the beginning.

Comment: I got this error for the above command: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'lorcz'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Answer (score 57):

If you are using `homebrew` you can use

```
brew services restart mysql
brew services start mysql
brew services stop mysql
```

for a list of available services

```
brew services list
```

Comment: This worked for me, even after interacting with launchctl directly did not. Thank you!

Comment: @Jan omg, thank you so much, your answer helped a lot

Comment: This worked but I have to specify MySQL version with it.
brew services restart mysql@5.7

Answer (score 30):

In my case, it kept on restarting as soon as I killed the process using PID. Also `brew stop` command didn't work as I installed without using homebrew. Then I went to mac system preferences and we have MySQL installed there. Just open it and stop the MySQL server and you're done. Here in the screenshot, you can find MySQL in bottom of system preferences. [image]

Comment: Worked for direct install through .pkg, version 8.0.27-arm64 on Big Sur.

Comment: System Settings > MySQL > Stop. This worked for me, almost the same thing, thanks!

Answer (score 23):

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop

Comment: +1 this was only one that worked for me---I just used the DMG installer from Mysql. Thanks

Comment: for me its giving this error. `$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop  
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
`

Comment: This is the only one that works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15):

`sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper stop`

You can also use start and restart here. I found this by looking at the contents of /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist.

Comment: This is how you're supposed to do it..  For MacPorts.. The `launchctl` method does NOT work, and in fact can cause problems with PID / DB startup bitching and moaning.

Answer (score 12):

Apparently you want:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
```

Have a further read in *[Jeez People, Stop Fretting Over Installing RMagic](http://www.simplisticcomplexity.com/2007/10/27/start-and-stop-mysql-in-mac-os-x-105-leopard/)*.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
sudo <path to mysql>/support-files/mysql.server start
sudo <path to mysql>/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Else try:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop<br>
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart
```

However, I found that the second option only worked (OS X 10.6, MySQL 5.1.50) if the .plist has been loaded with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

PS: I also found that I needed to unload the .plist to get an unrelated install of [MAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP)-MySQL to start / stop correctly. After running running this, MAMP-MySQL starts just fine:

sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
sudo mysqladmin shutdown --user=*user* --password=*password*
```

One could probably get away with not using [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). The *user* could be root for example (that is, the MySQL root user).

Answer (score 9):

On my mac osx yosemite 10.10. This command worked:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

You can find your mysql file in folder /Library/LaunchDaemons/ to run

Comment: This is only way that worked for me. For any other methods, the `mysqld` process restarts immediately after stopped.

Comment: This is the only way which worked for me too. I switched from homebrew to the MySQL-supplied DMG and I think possibly the brew version was still running even though I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 9):

For Mac M1 Pro, Go to system settings and Mysql at the bottom, Then click on stop MySQL server:

[image: Stop MySQL server]

Answer (score 6):

Get instance name:

```
ls /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep mysql
```

Stop MySQL instance (Works on MacOS Catalina, MySQL 8):

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Or, you can Stop MySQL instance in

```
MacOS Settings > MySQL > Stop MySQL Server
```

Also, check here for more methods:
https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-start-stop-restart-mysql-server.html

Answer (score 5):

Latest OSX (10.8) and mysql 5.6, the file is under Launch Daemons and is com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist. It presents an option under System Options, usually the bottom of the list. So go to system settings, click on Mysql, and turn it off from the option box.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-launchd.html

Answer (score 4):

Well, if all else fails, you could just take the ruthless approach and kill the process running MySQL manually.

That is,

```
ps -Af
```

to list all processes, then do "`kill <pid>`" where `<pid>` is the process id of the MySQL daemon (mysqld).

Comment: yeah.. this one is the best and universal for scripting. Do you think there is possibility of data corruption? or any other problems?

Comment: This has the potential for data corruption.

Comment: But as a last ditch effort, this is adequate.

Answer (score 3):

For me the following solution worked [Unable to stop MySQL on OS X 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375253/unable-to-stop-mysql-on-os-x-10-10)

To stop the auto start I used:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

And to kill the service I used:

```
sudo pkill mysqld
```

Answer (score 3):

As @gediminas said

System Preferences > MySQL > Stop MySQL Server

Was the easiest way. With binary installer downloaded from Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

For me it's working with a "mysql5"

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

On OSX Snow Leopard

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the MySQL 5 package with MacPorts:

```
sudo launchctl  unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
```

Or

```
sudo launchctl  unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5-devel.plist
```

if you installed the `mysql5-devel` package.

Comment: This will stop it from starting when you reboot, which is not what the poster was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

After try all those command line, and it is not work.I have to do following stuff:

```
mv /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/bin/mysqld /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/bin/mysqld.bak
mysql.server stop
```

This way works, the mysqld process is gone. but the /var/log/system.log have a lot of rubbish:

```
Jul  9 14:10:54 xxx com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql[78049]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jul  9 14:10:54 xxx com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on macOS 10.13.6 with  8.0.12 MySQL

`/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

`/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

`/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`

Answer (score 0):

I installed mysql5 and mysql55 over macports. For me the mentioned files here are located at the following places:

(mysql55-server)
/opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql55-server/org.macports.mysql55-server.plist

(mysql5)
/opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/org.macports.mysql5.plist

So stopping for these works like this:

mysql55-server:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql55-server/org.macports.mysql55-server.plist
```

mysql5:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/org.macports.mysql5.plist
```

You can check if the service is still running with:

```
ps ax | grep mysql
```

Further you can check the log files in my case here:

mysql55-server

```
sudo tail -n 100 /opt/local/var/db/mysql55/<MyName>-MacBook-Pro.local.err
...
130213 08:56:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/local/var/db/mysql55/<MyName>-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
```

mysql5:

```
sudo tail -n 100 /opt/local/var/db/mysql5/<MyName>-MacBook-Pro.local.err
...
130213 09:23:57  mysqld ended
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql> show variables where variable_name like '%dir%';

| datadir                                 | /opt/local/var/db/mysql5/               |