# How to stop mysqld

Tags: mysql, macos

To find out the start command for mysqld (using a mac) I can do:

```
ps aux|grep mysql
```

I get the following output, which allows me to start mysql server.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=...
```

How would I find the necessary command to stop mysql from the command line?

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install?rq=1

Comment: This work for me:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/529302/how-to-stop-mysqld-process
Maybe it will work for you too bro. []'s

Comment: The question was for a Mac.

Comment: If you're connected via the `mysql` client, you can just [type `SHUTDOWN` at the prompt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/shutdown.html).

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Try:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

Or:

```
sudo mysqld stop
```

Or:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld stop
```

Or:

```
sudo mysql.server stop
```

If you install the **Launchctl in OSX** you can try:

### MacPorts

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
```

Note: this is persistent after reboot.

### Homebrew

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

### Binary installer

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart
```

I found that in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/102094/58768

Comment: Thanks, `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root shutdown` did the trick.

Comment: If it's a dev environment and no password is defined, this would work: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root shutdown `

Comment: the middle option worked, but only with the addition of "service ": service mysqld stop

Comment: mysqladmin is sometimes in /usr/bin . Try, as root:
`/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`

Comment: Oh my god, why I use all these above and it's still running? It's like a virus!

Comment: @Zen do you use OSX?! If yes, you probaly set the LauchCTL system to make MySQL running all the time, look at `https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html` to learn more about!

Comment: @zen you can check in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons` , `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` look for any file with mysql in name.

Comment: @zen I found a link that helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install

Comment: What if i'm running mysql as `$ mysqld`? (just in the terminal). How would i kill it then? Because CTRL-C doesn't work.. I know `kill` would kill it, but just wondering if there's an escape sequence that mysqld listens to.

Comment: @matejkramny did you mean when you use a mysql client in terminal? `mysqld` is a daemon version with runs in background and can be stopped by `sudo mysqld stop`. If you are using as client, you must to send `quit` command and hit enter.

Comment: @BrunnoDosSantos i meant when mysqld runs in foreground in a terminal. Sorry for badly wording that.

Comment: @matejkramny you can send `quit` to exit client and shotdow server with one of options of answer.

Comment: @BrunnoDosSantos may I check why you run `unload` and then `load` again?

Comment: @fuzzbee I think that I don't explain in a good way. Sorry about that. That kind of Launchctl is used to run software in boot, so if you want to stop you can use unload at once. And if you want mysql run again when you boot you system use load. (sorry about bad english)

Comment: i had the same situation today.
Even if i had **su root** in my terminal , then executed: `service mysql stop` - that still brought up : 'unknown job: mysql', only when i ran the complete: `sudo service mysql stop` - it worked.

Comment: right, so executing service mysql with the wrong user rights brings up 'unknown job: mysql',
the environment is not changed unless the -l (or -) is provided to `su` , so doing `sudo root` before `service mysql stop` is not enough

Comment: 'sudo mysqladmin shutdown' is what did it for me

Comment: 'sudo mysqld stop' worked in my Mac with high sierra

Comment: None of the commands above works for me. When I type in sudo lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN it still shows the mysqld running listening to port 3306.

Comment: For me (Mac OS, 5.7.38 installed via Brew), `mysqld stop` just tries to run it and then complains that it's already running.  `mysql.server stop` did the trick.

Comment: `brew services stop mysql` worked for me

Answer (score 44):

There is an alternative way of just killing the daemon process by calling

```
kill -TERM PID
```

where `PID` is the value stored in the file `mysqld.pid` or the mysqld process id which can be obtained by issuing the command `ps -a | grep mysqld`.

Comment: this is a nice to know b/c it actually kills the process after it kept getting respawned when "kill -9 PID" just did not do it.

Comment: @lordB8r what does b/c it mean? I tried kill -9 mysqld(pid) but it restart immediately after that, this is torturing me.

Comment: @Zen Use `kill -TERM mysqld(pid)` instead and the entire process tree will be killed, not allowing it to be respawned.

Comment: Is this safe, cannot this lead to data corruption?

Comment: Yes, the operation is safe as RDBs guarantee ACID properties.

Comment: I tried the kill -term PID and it did kill it but if I run ps -a | grep mysqld, the process mysqld is started again with a new PID.

Comment: Use `kill -TERM mysqld(pid)` instead. If that does not work, there may be a respawning mechanism in place on your machine. Some places to check and verify if that is the case are suggested here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163603/how-to-find-source-of-spawning-process

Answer (score 33):

I did it with next command:

```
sudo killall mysqld
```

Answer (score 20):

[I found the answer here.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14161415%2Fmysql-process-cannot-be-stopped&ei=FY-jVL7lCYW7ogSW4YGYDQ&usg=AFQjCNHiQOFyHXl0uiCYxwNeYfj-ZRsHNg&sig2=lCsaaeNIJyEmVQizzWv-4A)

Use

```
sudo stop mysql
```

Comment: This worked for my AWS ubuntu mysql installation. The 'kill -TERM pid' did not work for my case. Thanks.

Comment: `sudo mysql stop` for me (Digital Ocean - ghost-512mb-lon1-01).

Comment: I got this error for that: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 20):

For Windows, you can run this command directly if mysql/bin is in your path.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

Answer (score 20):

## Worked for me on mac

#### a) Stop the process

```
sudo launchctl list | grep -i mysql
```

**If the result shows anything like:** "xxx.xxx.mysqlxxx"

```
sudo launchctl remove xxx.xxx.mysqlxxx
```

> Example:
> `sudo launchctl remove org.macports.mysql56-server`

#### b) Disable to autostart the process

```
sudo launchctl unload -wF /Library/LaunchDaemons/xxx.xxx.mysqlxxx.plist
```

> Example:
> `sudo launchctl unload -wF /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql56-server.plist`

- Finally reboot your mac

Note: In some cases if you tried **"a)"** first, you need to reboot again before try **b)**.

Answer (score 20):

When mysql was installed with Homebrew, it automatically restarts when killed. You need to use the following command:

```
brew services stop mysql
```

**PS**: If you installed a specific version, it will be `mysql@X.X`

Comment: I discovered the same! So simple. I wish brew had just announced it has a `services` section, and also that such services can't be shut down from the outside with `sudo` (which, btw, seems sketchy)

Comment: If it's a specific version, you need to find the specific version using `brew services list` and then `brew services stop mysql@5.7`. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124974/mysqld-keeps-automatically-restarting

Answer (score 14):

On OSX 10.8 and on, the control for MySQL is available from the System Configs. Open System Preferences, click on Mysql (usually on the very bottom) and start/stop the service from that pane.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-launchd.html

The plist file is now under /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

Comment: For the record, I tried all of the above methods and none of them worked to stop the extra MySQL process. Going through System Preferences & searching for MySQL did the trick - thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this worked. This is also where you find the uninstall button.

Comment: This worked for most:  https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d but to be safe, try Step 7 before Step 6

Answer (score 10):

for Binary installer use this:

to stop:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
```

to start:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
```

to restart:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart
```

Answer (score 7):

Try killing mysqld four times in a row.  It's the only thing that worked for me...

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/init# killall -KILL mysqld 
root@ubuntu:/etc/init# killall -KILL mysqld 
root@ubuntu:/etc/init# killall -KILL mysqld 
root@ubuntu:/etc/init# killall -KILL mysqld 
mysqld: no process found
```

Just keep killing it over and over until you see "mysqld: no process found".

Comment: This seems like a workaround. Why 4 times? Not a good solution.

Comment: Underrated, but it works.

Comment: The process that wouldn't die....

Answer (score 6):

Kill is definitly the wrong way! The PID will stay, Replicationsjobs will be killed etc. etc.

**STOP MySQL Server**

> /sbin/service mysql stop

**START MySQL Server**

> /sbin/service mysql start

**RESTART MySQL Server**

> /sbin/service mysql restart

Perhaps sudo will be needed if you have not enough rights

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me on CentOS 6.4 was running `service mysqld stop` as the root user.

I found my answer on [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-startup-script-under-bsdlinux/).

Comment: The question is about mac

Answer (score 3):

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld

When you see the following information, you success

mysql: no process found
mysqld_safe: no process found
mysqld: no process found
```

I use this to solve the installation problem of MySQL 5.6 in Ubuntu 15.10 using [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).

During this installation, I encounter the problem saying:

```
"mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists"
```

Just completely stop the mysqld, mysqld_safe, mysql solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If my mysql keeps restarting 
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/dev.work.err`
`mysql.server stop`
 worked for me.

Comment: mysql.server stop prompted this error: zsh: command not found: mysql.server

Answer (score 2):

To stop autostart of mysql on boot, the following worked for me with mysql `8.0.12` installed using Homebrew in `macOS Mojave 10.14.1`:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

To stop MariaDB and MySQL server instance:

```
sudo mysqladmin shutdown
```

To start MariaDB and MySQL server instance:

```
mysqld &
```

To change data ownership for MariaDB and MySQL server instance:

```
sudo chown -R 755 /usr/local/mariadb/data
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Just go to task manager.
2. Then in process, search mysqld.
3. right click on mysqld then click on stop.
4. with this process you can stop it without using commands.

Answer (score 1):

first try this

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

if not, then

```
sudo mysql stop
```

if not, then

```
sudo stop mysql
```

if not, then

```
sudo mysqladmin shutdown
```

I have been there, and I do with many tips, at the end of using tips that I follow will lead me to solved. So if you not solve in this issue, you just do other tips, till your issue get solved. Hopefully it's will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sudo launchctl list | grep -i mysql

```
sudo launchctl remove xxx.xxx.mysqlxxx
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

For mysql 5.7 downloaded from binary file onto MacOS:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

### Following worked for me on my macbook pro:

> brew services stop mysql

Incase if you want to stop all brew services:

> brew services stop --all

Answer (score 0):

if all else fails, this help me. Every time I tried to kill the process with the last installation it will respawn.

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql`

`brew reinstall mysql`

Answer (score -1):

## For MAMP

1. Stop servers (but you may notice MySQL stays on)
2. Remove or rename `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/` which holds the `mysql.pid` and `mysql.sock.lock` files
3. When you go back to Mamp, you'll see MySQL is now off. You can "Start Servers" again.

Comment: this will give '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql' for UNIX socket file don't exists' in mysql_error_log file