# Unable to stop MySQL on OS X 10.10

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite

I'm starting to go nuts over this. 
I setup MySQL/Apache/PHP using the tutorial by Coolest Guides On The Planet. 
I'm guessing something went wrong as its not working as expected so I want to uninstall and try again.

The trouble is that I can't stop MySQL either by system preferences or command line. I keep trying suggestions on the net but so far unsuccessful. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Finally got around the autostart - Thanks to all who contributed and allowed me to see the way.

To stop the auto start I used:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

And to kill the service I used:

```
sudo pkill mysqld
```

Comment: yes! thank you. Couldn't figure out how to prevent it from auto starting back up. Even editing the com.mysql.mysql.plist to set autostart to false didn't help. this worked

Comment: Finally... thanks! Also instead of pkill you can just go to SysPreferenses/MySQL and press the stop button.

Comment: Thanks! And in my machine I used this command `sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`. Notice that the plist file name is slightly different.

Comment: ```sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.server.plist``` worked for me

Comment: Thanks  `sudo pkill mysqld` works for macOS High Sierra

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Super annoying that this isn't discussed on the Oracle site. Also, see comment below that the name now has ".oss" in it.

Comment: Thanks Hutlion `sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` works in Mojave

Answer (score 12):

This is what worked for me. It was listed under a different plist name:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Comment: I struggled with this for 8 hours. I upgraded from osx lion with mysql 5.5 to el capital and mysql 5.7. The new version installed correctly but for some reason I could never get it to start. Realized there was another mysql process already running but couldn't figure out how it was configured. Everytime I killed mysqld it re-appeared. Was caused by this launch control

Answer (score 12):

For Mac Users
kill -9 {pid} kept restarting the process. This was because I had MySQL Server running. On OSX I had to:

1- System Preferences.

2- Search for mysql.

3- Press the Stop MySQL Server button.

got it from a github issue, and it solved my problem

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4950#issuecomment-407145733

Comment: Thank you!!! This solved my issue as well... Couldn't close port 3306 without MySQL auto restarting.

Answer (score 8):

`brew services stop mysql@5.6` worked for me, when all else failed.

Answer (score 5):

I also got the same problem, *unable to stop MySql Sever through system preferences on macOS High Sierra*.

I did  `brew uninstall mysql`   on my terminal window.

now *I am able stop stop MySql Sever through system preferences*.

Since mysql was installed on my mac 2 ways binary as well as home brew.

Comment: You can find which version using `launchctl list|grep mysql`

`brew services stop mysql@5.7`

Answer (score 4):

in terminal

```
kill `pgrep mysqld`
```

this kills the mysqld process.

Comment: When I try this i get the message: 
-bash: kill: (205) - Operation not permitted

Comment: Prepend sudo. So,

`sudo kill pgrep mysqld`

Comment: Why not just use `pkill`?

Comment: This command gives me the following message: kill: illegal process id: pgrep
kill: illegal process id: mysqld

Comment: sudo pkill mysqld worked! BUT it almost instantly restarted :/
So tanks you for solving problem 1... please can you advise me now on problem 2... how do I stop it restarting?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you used `brew` then you can find out which version you are using by:

```
launchctl list|grep mysql
```

this will print something like

```
92555   0   homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7
```

In my case I'm using **mysql@5.7**

You can stop using:

```
brew services stop mysql@5.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with issuing the following command in command line:

```
ps -xo pid,ppid,stat,command | grep mysqld
```

It will show you your processes, with their parent ID in the second column. Look for the mysqld and it's parent process. After locating it, issue a:

```
sudo kill pid
```

where pid is mysqld's parent process ID.

**EDIT**
If you want to stop the process from launching again, try:

```
sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/mysqld.plist
```

Comment: in the cmd line response 603   597 U+   grep mysqld which is the parent process id?
Thanks

Comment: It's a 597. Try: `sudo kill 597` or if it fails, `sudo kill -9 597`

Comment: The second command said process completed but in system prefs MySQL is still running

Comment: Using sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/mysqld.plist gives me /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/mysqld.plist: No such file or directory

Comment: maybe try with 

`sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/mysql.plist`

Answer (score 1):

I've installed mysql via homebrew, but stop mysql by using `mysql stop` command, mysql restart right now.
try to execute command as follow if your mysql was installed via homebrew

```
brew services stop $(brew list | grep mysql)
```