# How to stop mysql on OsX from the command line

Tags: mysql, macos

This question bas many answers, I tried what I found – did not work

So, I tried sudo mysqld stop.
Still I see the mysql processes running:

```
0   317     1   0 11:15AM ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/anarinsky-mbp.smartdestinations.com.pid


74  3562   317   0 11:40AM ??         0:00.41 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/anarinsky-mbp.smartdestinations.com.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/anarinsky-mbp.smartdestinations.com.pid
```

The same happens if I do `“sudo kill -9 3562”.`

Trying to go to /Library/LaunchDaemons does not retrieve any mysql entries

```
ls /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep mysql
```

The service command does not work:

```
-bash: service: command not found
```

My Os X version is 10.9.2

Comment: Here's a suggestion; https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/  The kill command requires a process id (sudo kill -9 PIDxxx) and it will always work if you have the right pid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you stop MySQL on a Mac OS install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install)

Comment: Sure, I used PID of the process in kill-9. As I wrote I tried multiple recepies before

Answer (score 4):

There are two answers I know, it might not help since you search a long time.

1.if you install mysql from dmg, you can close it in "system preferences".

2.And besides that, you can start/stop/restart mysql by:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

Comment: doesnt work, it keeps getting restarted and those commands also give an error  ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be fou

Comment: System Preferences > MySQL > Stop Mysql worked for me. To find out where mysql is installed try: `type -a mysql`

Answer (score 2):

To install Homebrew, open Terminal/iTerm and run following command or check https://brew.sh/

- $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Install mysql

- `$ brew install mysql.`

Install brew services first

- `$ brew tap homebrew/services.`

Start mysql

- `$ brew services start mysql.`

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid mysqld from auto restarting after killed, try execute all these 3 commands:

```
$ brew services stop mysql
$ sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
$ sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```