# How to updated my.cnf file to increase innodb-buffer-pool-size?

Tags: python, mysql, my.cnf, max-pool-size, bufferpool

I am trying to updated the my.cnf file to increase the buffer pool size for a query I am running in python via mysql because I keep getting the error:

```
OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Now I have located the file and get:

```
/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.30/.bottle/etc/my.cnf
```

Now I am trying to figure out how update this file. I have read using sudo command then enter the password, which I do but I get command not found. I am assuming I am doing this wrong.

```
sudo: /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf: command not found
```

Any and all help will be much appreciated.

---

After attempting to do the nano command my screen gives me this. So leads me to believe that this is not where the file is.

This is what is seen when doing this command:

```
sudo /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
```

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: `my.conf` is not a command you run, it's a text file that you edit.

Comment: to update the cnf use an editor; either vi or nano -> sudo nano /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

Change the my.cnf file as follows:

Launch a terminal and go to the directory containing the my.cnf file. In your instance, it's at `/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf` or `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.30/.bottle/etc/my.cnf`.

To open the file with the nano text editor, use `sudo nano my.cnf`. If you are log in as sudo try to use `nano my.cnf` without sudo.

After opening the file, go to the [mysqld] section and add the following line:
`value innodb buffer pool size` (replace value with the desired buffer pool size in bytes)

To save the modifications, use Ctrl + O, and to quit nano, press Ctrl + X.

To make the modifications take effect, restart the MySQL server. Depending on your system, you may do this by typing'sudo service mysql restart' or'sudo systemctl restart mysql'.

If you do not want to use nano, you can use any text editor of your choice.

Comment: I tried your answer, and thank you for replying, but I believe this is not where the file lives

Comment: @Astro_raf I think that's the default for ARM based Macs. We found the arm user lol

Answer (score 1):

The command you posted attempts to run the my.cnf file like it was a program:

```bash
# NO!Do not do this.
sudo /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
```

If you want to edit a file, you can use a program like [nano](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nano) to edit this file:

```bash
sudo nano /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
```

That will show you the contents of the my.cnf file and you can use the cursor keys to move around and make changes to the file. BE CAREFUL. You should probably make a backup of the file before attempting any changes.

When you are satisfied, hit ctrl-o to output the changes and then ctrl-x to exit nano, then [restart mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install) for the changes to take effect.

If you are not sure where your my.cnf file is located, it can be sorta tricky to find. Evidently MySQL will sometimes load more than one my.cnf file, each overriding the last. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location).

You may find this command helpful to locate all the files named 'my.cnf' on your machine's file system:

```bash
sudo find / -name "my.cnf" 2>/dev/null
```

There's also a pretty cool tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-mysql-configuration-file-is-being-used) which works on my ubuntu workstation but may or may not for your macos situation. First, find out where mysqld is:

```bash
which mysqld
```

In my case, this returns `/usr/sbin/mysqld` which I use to create this command:

```bash
/usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
```

The output of that command lists 3 my.cnf file locations. Yours may be different.

**AFTER MAKING CHANGES TO MY.CNF DON'T FORGET TO RESTART MYSQL.**

Comment: I tried your answer, and thank you for replying, but I believe this is not where the file lives.

Comment: @Astro_raf I've added some additional detail about how to locate your my.cnf files.