# MySQL Database in XAMPP not starting on mac

Tags: mysql, xampp

I want to run a MySQL Database via XAMPP.

Whenever I attempt to start my MySQL Database, it just stops. I tried starting it in the terminal using "sudo Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start"
The result is:
"Starting MySQL
SUCCESS!
root@user-MacBook-Pro bin # 2024-02-13T10:54:02.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists"

After that i tried to kill the process using "sudo mysql stop"
result:
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Then I tried killing the process by using "kill -9 " but the process just simply started again.The process name being "mysqld".

I also tried reinstalling XAMPP and switching Port.

Now, I'm unsure of what steps to take next.
Thank you for your answers, and I hope you can assist me.

Comment: xampp has normally mariadb installed, a mysql server would start on the same port 3306. Either disable the maridb server or use a different port for mariadb or mysql

Comment: `sudo mysql stop` aim to connect to mysql server. Take a look at this post: [How do you stop a MySQL on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install)